# IIS Web Site working fine with HTTP but not with HTTPS

Tags: iis

My site working fine with HTTP (On localhost) but when i run this on https it says .

This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Following are the action that i did
#1.site is running on localhost on 443 port
#2.Generated self signed certificate

Please let me know what is causing the issue

Regards,

Comment: If you run a report, the cause should be clear, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: site working fine in IE with https not on other browsers

Comment: That’s because all others are modern browsers, while IE is not.

Comment: so do you want me to run ssl diagnostics ?

Comment: is this issue related to SSL ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the site is accessible using HTTP.

set up the iis site binding as below to make it work using https:

[image]

if you have purchased a domain name then you can add it in the host name field.

if you are running the site in an Azure virtual machine make sure you have added 443 port in the azure firewall setting.

Comment: Thanks for your response , I already configured site using same config, here is the issue ,            --Https is only working with Internet explorer not with other browser                                     ----Http is working fine ,                                                                                                               i have to make site working with https on all browsers

Comment: @PrabhakarDwivedi could you download and install iis crypto, after installing set the best practice in it, and reboot the machine.